# 15 inch Macbook Pro with Retina Display-dual Gateway monitors

Tags: display, thunderbolt, macbook-pro, vga-adapter, vga

I am currently running dual monitors from a Gateway desktop. I would love to upgrade to a MacBook Pro, but would like to keep my two monitors. Is there an (easy) way to dual monitor non-Apple monitors from a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. The Retina MacBook Pro has one HDMI output and two Thunderbolt ports, so you can run the internal display and three external monitors as long as you can accept HDMI on your *third* monitor (with or without an adapter/converter).

Any [mini-DisplayPort adapter from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/A) will work from Thunderbolt in addition to adapters labeled as Thunderbolt.

Comment: From Apple http://support.apple.com/kb/SP653  

Graphics and Video Support: Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, at millions of colors